# Regular expression alphanumerics with space

Tags: asp.net, regex

I write regular expression for alphanumerics, but it is not taking space.
I want space (whitespace between characters).
I write like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `\s` escape sequence that mean "whitespace".

Change you regex to this (adding whitespace to the list of characters):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*$
```

As noted by Alex, `\w` stands for word characters, so you could shorten it further:

```
^[\w\s]*$
```

See [this](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) handy cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
^[\w\s]*$
```

would be shorter?

`\w` means word characters (letters, digits, and underscores).

I prefer [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) cheat sheet (print).